# Filter Text through list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have a list of stopwords (in German) that i want to use to Filter out the same ones from an input Text, it looks like this:

```
stopwortlist = ['ab', 'aber','abgesehen', 'alle', 'allein', 'aller', 'alles']
text = input('please put in a Text')
#i have found a way of controlling them online, but it doesnt quite work,
#cause it gives out a list, and all i want is a text (where the words from 
#the list are filtered out

def filterStopwords (eingabeText, stopwords):

    out = [word for word in eingabeText if word not in stopwords]
    return out;
```

how should i modify the function to get my Result ?
thanks a lot in Advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a one liner using the filter and join methods.

```
stopwortlist = ['ab', 'aber','abgesehen', 'alle', 'allein', 'aller', 'alles']
text = 'There are ab aber multiple allein abgesehen words in alles this ab list'

print " ".join(filter(lambda x: x not in stopwortlist, text.split()))

#Output
There are multiple words in this list
```

This basically uses a lambda function to check if a word is in the `stopwortlist` and then filters it out of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Split your incoming text into words (otherwise you are iterating over characters), filter the stop words and then rejoin the resulting list.

```
stopwortlist = ['ab', 'aber','abgesehen', 'alle', 'allein', 'aller', 'alles']
text = 'Some text ab aber with stopwords allein in'

def filterStopwords(eingabeText, stopwords):
    out = [word for word in eingabeText.split() if word not in stopwords]
    return ' '.join(out)

filterStopwords(text, stopwortlist) # => 'Some text with stopwords in'
```